# "Add Folder" not showing in Salesforce CMS Workspaces

Tags: community-builder, topics, folder, contentworkspace, salesforce-cms

Why can I not see the "Add Folder" or "Move Content" options in my CMS Workspace - I only see "Add Content" - I have full admin permissions in the org and as contributor in the workspace?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The buttons "Add Folders" and "Move Content" have been added to the UI as part of the Winter'21 release.
See the release notes https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_cms_folders.htm

I have been able to replicate and confirm this behavior in my Summer'20 and Winter'21 Orgs.

**Summer'20 Org**:
[image]
**Winter'21 Org**
[image]

Note: The CMS Folder, Move content permission have been launched as a [pilot program](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000194013&language=en_US&type=1&mode=1) earlier

Comment: @Donné Mitchell Let me know if this answers your query or if you have any additional queries

Comment: Thank you Swetha, your answer is correct, and I can now access these folders with the Winter'21 release.